# Bitnami will work for the first time but won't work the second time I try to access it

Tags: wordpress

It won't open the local host site again once I have shut it down because the connection has timed out.

I tried starting the website on a virtual machine on virtualbox but it just won't start the second time and there is nothing happening. Unable to view the site.